# .htaccess rewrite to add country code (if missing)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a .htaccess file in the subdirectory /cms and using this subdirectory as RewriteBase. The redirections go to 'backend.php' and send the variables I want. It is a dual language site (nl|en), dutch and english. Everything works fine, as long as the %{REQUEST_URI} starts with (nl|en).

But I need a fallback to the default dutch language when nl|en is omitted, but can I add this to the following .htacces file. I have been trying and searching but cannot find the right syntax to make this happen:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^(nl|en)/)
#RewriteRule (.*) This is where the solution should be used ?

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^(nl|en)/([^/]+)/$ backend.php?page=$2&language=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule (nl|en)(.*)/(\d+)/$ backend.php?page=$2&id=$3&language=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule (nl|en)(.*)/(\d+)/(.+)/$ backend.php?page=$2&id=$3&task=$4&language=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is a rewrite with the dutch language prepended. This will silently change direction to the proper page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/(?:nl|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ nl/$1 [L]
```

If you want the client to notice and change the URL, you must do a [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) instead

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/(?:nl|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ nl/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that is I think the way to go (of course), but when I use:

RewriteRule !^(?:nl|en)/ nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L], this should happen:

http://mysite:8888/cms/nl/overview/ - is the valid URL

This is what happens: 

http://mysite:8888/cms/overzicht/ -after rewrite becomes:
http://mysite:8888/cms/nl/cms/overzicht/

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that is I think the way to go (of course), but when I use:

RewriteRule !^(?:nl|en)/ nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L], this should happen:

http://mysite:8888/cms/nl/overview/ - is the valid URL

This is what happens: 

http://mysite:8888/cms/overzicht/ -after rewrite becomes:
http://mysite:8888/cms/nl/cms/overzicht/

The cms part of the URL is repeated, obviously because it is part of the %{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: @D.M.P Yes, I missed that, sorry. Please see, if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your time, it almost works. I have to tweak a bit to get it working over all nested subs but you solved my problem. Redirect is the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your default rule can be this one:

```
# This is where the solution should be used ?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(nl|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ backend.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```